# How to get resource ID from Image Path?

Tags: android, imageview

I have an imagepath in android .This image exits on the sdcard of the device. How can i find resourceID of it ? I need to send it to decodeResource function. I am trying to detect faces on the image user selects from the gallery. The code that I have written is

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetectFaces.class);
    intent.putExtra(PICTURE_PATH,picturePath);//the path of the image
    startActivity(intent);
```

In detectFaces class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detect_faces);
       // getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        picturePath = intent.getStringExtra(GetFaceActivity.PICTURE_PATH);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        //imageView.setOnTouchListener(this);

    }
```

There is a button whose onClick event is associated with

```
public void DetectFacesInImage(View view)
{
    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapFactoryOptions=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapFactoryOptions.inPreferredConfig= Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
myBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.faceswapping,bitmapFactoryOptions);
    int width=myBitmap.getWidth();
    int height=myBitmap.getHeight();
    detectedFaces=new FaceDetector.Face[number_of_faces];
    FaceDetector faceDetector=new FaceDetector(width,height,number_of_faces);
    number_of_faces_detected = faceDetector.findFaces(myBitmap, detectedFaces);

 }
```

I need ID in the decodeResource function. Any hints ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it may help you

```
File fileObj = new  File(“/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg”);
if(fileObj .exists()){
    Bitmap bitMapObj= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileObj .getAbsolutePath());
    ImageView imgView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(bitMapObj);
}
```

Comment: but where are you finding resourceID of the image in it ?

Comment: You do not need resource id to decode a file. You need resource id, only if this particular image is in your resource folder. But you mentioned that the image is available on the sd card. You will not get a resource id for anything, which is not there in your apk.

Comment: Durairaj P, you should edit your comment as an answer 'cos I think that's what he is trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to decode an image, you need to get the get the file path by using a query to mediastore. You can use something like this

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(column_index);


    }
```

Comment: I have the imagePath but now I need to use decodeResource() which requires the resID, so I want to find that from imagePath