# Convert local image file to resource ID

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources, android-file

I have an image file locally stored in my phone memory(or, SD card). From my code, I am totally able to open the file an convert it to Bitmap and do stuff. But I need a **resource id** instead. I am not sure how to get the **resource id** (i.e. int) from a Bitmap or file path. Can anybody help?

Comment: "But I need a resource id instead" -- why you think that you need a resource ID? Perhaps we can suggest alternative approaches to the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879035/how-to-get-resource-id-from-image-path]

Comment: I was trying to add the user icon to the left navigation drawer in my app. A drawable resource id was needed for that. But have found another approach for adding drawable directly. Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get a resource ID for a file on the filesystem of the device. Resources are files compiled into your APK; they are not files on the filesystem of a device.

Comment: I understand that now. I have been able to solve the issue now by adding drawable directly. I am pretty new to android. Dumb question indeed.  I will mark your answer to this.